# Physical disk 1 not showing on disk2vhd.exe

Tags: windows-8.1, disk2vhd

I open up Computer Management, I shrank my drive by 30 gigabytes and formatted the shrank space to the NTFS file system. I didn't add a volume label added default to Allocation unit size and checked perform a quick format. After that I opened disk2vhd.exe then looked in disk target and only saw physical disk 0!
I don't want to modify the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}` because I think that's way too risky.

[image: Local Disk Properties]

Comment: Any help anyone??

Comment: Did you run `disk2vhd.exe` as administrator?

Comment: Yes I did run it as administrator and it didn't work

Comment: I even tried to add partition primary I'ts a volume I created partition primary with diskpart

Comment: disk2vhd tell for itself then. It DISK to vhd, not partition to VHD.

Comment: Check this: http://superuser.com/questions/219228/convert-partition-to-virtual-disk-image

Comment: If i select physical disk 0 and hit vhd to disk will it destroy windows 8.1???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually *add* a physical disk. You added a *partition* to the same physical disk 0.

I mean, that's why Windows calls it "physical disk" – it references the device inside your computer. The only way you can get a `PhysicalDisk1` is by literally connecting it via USB or SATA.

Comment: is there any partition to physical disk then??

Comment: If i select physical disk 0 and hit vhd to disk will it destroy windows 8.1???

Comment: I thought you said disk2vhd, not vhd2disk?...

Comment: Post deleted https://superuser.com/questions/1194650/tried-to-run-vmware-but-error-happens?noredirect=1#comment1736203_1194650 Wasn't well recieved

Comment: Post deleted https://superuser.com/questions/1197825/ubuntu-boots-into-busybox-tried-one-of-the-following-but-didnt-work/1197865#1197865 Already answered my own question

Comment: Post undeleted https://superuser.com/questions/1197825/ubuntu-boots-into-busybox-tried-one-of-the-following-but-didnt-work/1197865#1197865 Already answered my own question