# ubuntu boots into busybox tried one of the following but didn't work

Tags: ubuntu, busybox

right before it boots into busybox i caught this error error: failure reading sector 0xbffc from hd0 I tried one of your suggestions i typed root=/dev/sda1 but it still boots into busybox
 I tried mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /root -o force
error 1
NTFS signature is missing,
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disl instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /root failed: No such device
I still get error 1 when i try mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda /root -o force
when i try fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root -y
I get this
error 2
fsck from util-linux 2.29
e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continu, aborting.
I type reboot but still get error: failure reading sector 0xbffc from hd0
so next busybox boot i type exit but then 
Kernel panic - Attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00000200
i get stuck there
booted sd card with legacy & uefi but i get that error
mmc0: Unknown controller version (3). You may experience problems 
No Caching mode page found
blk_update_request: i/o error, 2097136
Buffer i/o error on dev sr1, logical block 49148
then it boots into busybox again! in sd card
sd card contains ubuntu installation
using ubuntu 17.04 zesty zapus beta 2
i don't have a bootable usb just a bootable sd card

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out i was supposed to enable secure boot!
and enable uefi

Comment: I know it's been so long but why downvote this?

Comment: Heeelllloooo???

Comment: .....................Anyone?